# Date Comparison in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I'm trying to check if the time between two dates is larger than 3 months, but have had no success. Here is what I am trying. Am I doing something incorrectly? Even if I set the detailTextDate at yesterday, it will still display the evaluationLabel. Do I need to set a dateFormat?

```
    NSString *detailTextDate = @"August 11, 2013";

    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    dateFormatter.dateStyle = NSDateFormatterLongStyle;

    NSDate *startDate = [dateFormatter dateFromString:detailTextDate];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss"];
    NSDate *todaysDate = [NSDate date];

    NSCalendar *gregorianCalendar = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
    NSDateComponents *components = [gregorianCalendar components:NSMonthCalendarUnit
                                                        fromDate:startDate
                                                          toDate:todaysDate
                                                         options:0];
    if(components.month >= 3){
        evaluationLabel.hidden = NO;
    }

}

//tried using NSYearCalendarUnit, Month, Day etc.

//startDate = 2013-08-11 06:00:00 +0000, detailTextDate = August 11, 2013, components = //<NSDateComponents: 0x176c3c70>
//    Month: 0
```

Comment: When you debugged this, what were the actual values of the dates?

Comment: You are interested in actual calendar months, not just, say, 90 days?

Comment: @IanHenry: It can be 3 months, 90 days, seconds, milliseconds, it doesn't matter, as long as the time is still equivalent. I also tried doing it in days.

Comment: @CarlVeazey: I added what NSLogging returned in my question.

Comment: Are you certain the label is hidden already? Does execution actually enter the body of the if statement?

Comment: @CarlVeazey: Solved it. See answer below. No idea why that worked?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my issue. Not sure why but this works. Hope I help someone in the future.

```
    NSString *detailTextDate = @"May 23, 2013";

    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];

    dateFormatter.dateStyle = NSDateFormatterLongStyle;



    NSDate *startDate = [dateFormatter dateFromString:detailTextDate];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss"];
    NSDate *todaysDate = [NSDate date];

    NSCalendar *gregorianCalendar = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
    NSDateComponents *components = [gregorianCalendar components:NSDayCalendarUnit
                                                        fromDate:startDate
                                                          toDate:todaysDate
                                                         options:0];

        NSLog(@"startDate = %@, detailTextDate = %@, components = %ld", startDate, detailTextDate, (long)components.day);
    if(components.day >= 90){
        evaluationLabel.hidden = NO;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're only asking for `NSYearCalendarUnit`; you probably want to be asking for `NSMonthCalendarUnit`.

Comment: Also, `NSDate *todaysDate = [dateFormatter dateFromString:[dateFormatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]]];` is redundant; you only need to do `NSDate *todaysDate = [NSDate date];`.

Comment: Thanks, missed that. Have no idea why I did it that way.

Answer (score 0):

The following logs `12` for `[component month]` and 9 for `[component day]` (note that I changed the start date since, in your example, the month difference would be zero):

```
  NSString *detailTextDate = @"August 11, 2012";

  NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
  dateFormatter.dateStyle = NSDateFormatterLongStyle;

  NSDate *startDate = [dateFormatter dateFromString:detailTextDate];
  NSDate *todaysDate = [NSDate date];

  NSCalendar *gregorianCalendar = [[NSCalendar alloc]
                                   initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];

  NSUInteger flags = NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSDayCalendarUnit;
  NSDateComponents *components = [gregorianCalendar components:flags
                                                      fromDate:startDate
                                                        toDate:todaysDate
                                                       options:0];

  NSLog(@"%ld", (long)[components month]);
  NSLog(@"%ld", (long)[components day]);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"MMMM dd, yyyy"];
    NSDate *date1 = [dateFormatter dateFromString:detailTextDate];

    NSDate *todaysDate = [NSDate date];

    unsigned int unitFlags = NSDayCalendarUnit,NSMonthCalendarUnit,NSYearCalendarUnit;

    NSCalendar *gregorian = [[NSCalendar alloc]initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
    NSDateComponents *comps = [gregorian components:unitFlags fromDate:date1  toDate:todaysDate  options:0];

    int month = [comps month];
    NSLog(@"%d",month);

    if(month>0)
    {

    }
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use [`timeIntervalSinceNow`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDate_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSDate/timeIntervalSinceNow) to figure out how far in the past something occurred.

This returns an `NSTimeInterval`, which is just a `typedef` for a `double` representing a span of seconds. So you can do things like this:

```
NSTimeInterval month = 60.0 * 60.0 * 24.0 * 30.0;
NSTimeInterval timeUntilNow = -[startDate timeIntervalSinceNow];
if (timeUntilNow > month * 3.0) {
   ...
}
```

Comment: Calendar calculations based on time intervals are fraught with error. Also, this code equates a month to 72 minutes.

Comment: @IanHenry: tried it, made the evaluationLabel.hidden = NO; within the if statement, still shows the evaluationLabel. startDate is equal to yesterday.

Comment: @CarlVeazey Good catch on the month arithmetic. Not sure what you mean by "fraught with error," though. As far as my knowledge goes this (now) correctly tests if something happened 90 days ago, as the asker stated in a comment was desirable behavior.

Comment: @IanHenry There are lots of edge cases caused by not all months having 30 days, daylight savings time, leap seconds, etc. It's always best to use the provided API for doing date difference calculations. Time intervals is tricky because it might work in many cases but it can bite you in some unexpected ways.

Comment: @rmaddy That's true if you're interested in calendar date calculations. If you're not, as the poster specified, what's the problem with using time intervals?

Answer (score -1):

```
 NSString *detailTextDate = @"August 11, 2013";

 NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
 dateFormatter.dateStyle = NSDateFormatterLongStyle;

NSDate *enddate = [dateFormatter dateFromString:detailTextDate];
NSDate* currentdate = [NSDate date];
NSTimeInterval distanceBetweenDates = [enddate timeIntervalSinceDate:currentdate];
NSInteger secondsBetweenDates = distanceBetweenDates / 60;

if(secondsBetweenDates>0){
// Here you can compare seconds
}
```